# Visual Studio 2010 - cannot find color setting for identifier-matching

Tags: visual-studio-2010, color-scheme

I am looking for the option to set the background/highlight color for identifier-matches on Visual Studio.

For example, if I have an identifier:

```
int myNumber=0
```

Now, I put my cursor on into the middle of myNumber. Visual Studio highlights all other occurrances of myNumber on the page.

I cannot, for the life of me, find the color settings for this highlighting. At the moment in my color scheme it looks very much like the color for selected text. So, it is confusing and affects my productivity.

If anyone can track this down, you will be my hero.

Comment: Refer to the answer given at following question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640582/environment-setting-for-highlighted-variable-in-visual-studio?rq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a few months late, but the setting you're looking for is `Highlighted Reference`.

Comment: It doesn't work for me in VS2010

Answer (score 2):

Since this comes up in the first Google search result, I'll also add that you may also have to enable the option if the colour you have selected isn't working.  This is located in various places:

- Text Editor, [Basic, C#], Advanced, "Highlight references to symbol under cursor"
- Text Editor, C++, Advanced, "Disable Reference Highlighting"