# How do I change the highlighting of this variable in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I just installed 2015 and am trying to import my settings from 2013 but not everything is transferring correctly.

In the picture below, my cursor is on the variable declaration on the first line. What setting controls the highlighting on the lines where I assign values to test? I've been through the whole list in the fonts and colors section of the options, but can't seem to find it.

If it matters, I have ReSharper Ultimate installed, but no other extensions.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Environment Setting for Highlighted Variable in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640582/environment-setting-for-highlighted-variable-in-visual-studio)

Comment: I don't think it is. I've tried that setting and it didn't work. And the screen shot in the answer on that one doesn't show a line where the variable gets assigned, just where it's passed around and used in if statements. The highlighting on my if statement works fine. It's only when I'm assigning a value to the variable that it acts up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Documentation for custom fonts and colors in Visual Studio environment options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34657708/11683)

Comment: The answer on that question worked for me.